# $g$ and $h$ cannot work in garamondx package with newtxmath?

Tags: newtxmath, garamondx

I would like to use garamondx package with newtxmath, everything looks normal except `$g$` and `$h$`. Here is the code I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{garamondx} 
\usepackage[garamondx,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\useosf

\begin{document}
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

1234567890

$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$

$abcdefijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ %no g,h

$1234567890$


\end{document}
```

It will work without `gh`, but when I insert `gh` in math mode, it cannot work anymore.
Why?

When I added `$g$` or `$h$`, "Process started" said:

```
Trying to make PK font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw at 600 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The NewG8-Ita-alt-raw source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makemf: PK font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

It disappears very quickly, then the Log file appears:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.22)  23 OCT 2019 15:21
entering extended mode
**"garamondx-doc - Copy.tex"
("garamondx-doc - Copy.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.
Package textcomp Info: Changing ? sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 72.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\garamondx.sty"
Package: garamondx 2017/03/11 v1.12

`garamondx' v1.12. 2017/03/11 GaramondNo8 with expert features (Michael Sharpe)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ly1\ly1enc.def"
File: ly1enc.def 2009/07/22 v0.7 TeX 'n ANSI encoding (DPC/KB)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ptm on input line 100.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd"
File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontaxes\fontaxes.sty"
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2015/03/10 v2.1b e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\newtxmath.sty"
Package: newtxmath 2015/03/03 v1.412

`newtxmath' v1.412, 2015/03/03 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen105
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen106
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count91
\leftroot@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count93
\DOTSCASE@=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen107
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count95
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count97
\dspbrk@lvl=\count98
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count99
\column@=\count100
\maxfields@=\count101
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen108
\alignsep@=\dimen109
\tagshift@=\dimen110
\tagwidth@=\dimen111
\totwidth@=\dimen112
\lineht@=\dimen113
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks20
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks21
)
\XKV@depth=\count102
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\binhex\binhex.tex")
\tx@Isdigit=\count103
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 106.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/zgmx/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/zgmx/m/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/zgmx/m/n --> T1/zgmx/b/n on input line 107.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> T1/cmss/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> T1/cmss/m/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 114.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/zgmx/m/it on input line 114.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/zgmx/m/it on input line 114.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 117.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/zgmx/b/n on input line 117.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/zgmx/b/n on input line 117.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/zgmx/m/it --> T1/zgmx/b/it on input line 118.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/cmss/m/n --> T1/cmss/b/n on input line 119.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/b/n on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 136.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/zgmmi/m/it on input line 136.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/zgmmi/m/it on input line 136.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/zgmmi/m/it --> OML/zgmmi/b/it on input line 137.
\symlettersA=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxmia/m/it --> U/ntxmia/b/it on input line 170.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 178.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 178.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 178.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/ntxsy/m/n --> OMS/ntxsy/b/n on input line 179.
\symAMSa=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsya/m/n --> U/ntxsya/b/n on input line 195.
\symAMSb=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsyb/m/n --> U/ntxsyb/b/n on input line 204.
\symsymbolsC=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsyc/m/n --> U/ntxsyc/b/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 228.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 2
28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 228.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 228
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 228.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  LMX/ntxexx/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/b/n on input line 229.
\symlargesymbolsTXA=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsTXA' in version `bold'

(Font)                  U/ntxexa/m/n --> U/ntxexa/b/n on input line 243.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 327.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 328.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 329.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 330.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 331.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 332.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 333.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 335.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mid on input line 337.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \arrowvert on input line 339.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 340.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Arrowvert on input line 342.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 343.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \updownarrow on input line 345.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Updownarrow on input line 346.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 1628.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+zgmj on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\t1zgmj.fd"
File: t1zgmj.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmj.
)
("garamondx-doc - Copy.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/zgmmi/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+zgmmi on input line 7.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\omlzgmmi.fd"
File: omlzgmmi.fd 2012/11/18 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/zgmmi.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+ntxsy on input line 7.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\omsntxsy.fd"
File: omsntxsy.fd 2012/11/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMS/ntxsy.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/ntxexa/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxexa on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\untxexa.fd"
File: untxexa.fd 2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LY1+ptm on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ly1\ly1ptm.fd"
File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count104
\scratchdimen=\dimen114
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count105
\nofMParguments=\count106
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count107
\MPscratchDim=\dimen115
\MPnumerator=\count108
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count109
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
)
\c@mv@tabular=\count110
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count111
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+zgmx on input line 14.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\t1zgmx.fd"
File: t1zgmx.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmx.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxmia on input line 14.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\untxmia.fd"
File: untxmia.fd 2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsya on input line 14.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\untxsya.fd"
File: untxsya.fd 2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsya.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsyb on input line 14.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\untxsyb.fd"
File: untxsyb.fd 2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyb.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsyc on input line 14.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\newtx\untxsyc.fd"
File: untxsyc.fd 2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
) [1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] ("garamondx-doc - Copy.au
x") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4443 strings out of 493698
 56500 string characters out of 3144411
 100617 words of memory out of 3000000
 7694 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 35803 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,4n,33p,862b,117s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file NewG8-Ita-alt-raw): Font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw at 600
 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

You see at the end of Log file, it said

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file NewG8-Ita-alt-raw): Font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw at 600
     not found
     ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I use Miktex, win 10. I am a newbie in latex, please help me! Thank you!

Comment: I get the expected output if I add `gh`. What happens if you do?

Comment: @egreg I edited my question and added what happened. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution.